# how to send OTP on mobile number code

Tags: android

I want to make a sample in which I want that as the user enter 10 digits mobile number a OTP send to its mobile number,I just want to check whether in message box OTP come or not , if come then show a toast that "OTP send succesfully".

Comment: Sounds good. Let us know how you get on.

Comment: you'll have to get OTP from your webservice and then you'll have to use `BroadCast Receiver` to catch OTP from your inbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SmsManager`:

```
try {
    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, "generate otp   here", null, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    dialog.setMessage(e.getMessage());
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined , this error is coming what to do

Comment: In your OnCreate Method add this line   
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this); and then in 
@Override
       public void onClick(View v)  add the above code